# Getting error IndexOutOfRange in unity but still working

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, unity-game-engine

Below gets all my targets and randomly gives it to the enemy, which works 99% of the time but every enemy give the error IndexOutOfRange Index was outside the bounds of the array. The last 1% of the time the enemy is given no target and error on variable not assigned.

I found a few posts with this error where i got the -1 part from which helped but its still not working correctly.

```
     targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
     transArray = new Transform[Random.Range(0, targets.Length - 1)];

     for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length - 1; i++)
     {
         transArray[i] = targets[i].transform;

         target = transArray[i];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It should probably be `Random.Range(0, targets.Length)` since the second parameter is exclusive for `int`. Otherwise the last element would never be included.
2. In the case that `targets` is an empty array because `FindGameObjectsWithTag` didn't find any elements you would create an also empty `transArray` (`new Transform[0]`) so accessing the first index for `i = 0` would throw an exception
3. `transArray` is basically **always** smaller than `targets` so if anything you would rather iterate over `transArray.Length` not over the bigger `targets.Length`. Otherwise you get an exception as soon as `i` exceeds `transArray.Length - 1`
4. No idea what `target = transArray[i];` is supposed to do but it will always be the last element anyway. No need to do this in a loop. You could just after your loop do

   ```
   target = transArray[transArray.Length - 1];
   ```

   to get the last element of `transArray`.

So in total it should probably rather look like e.g.

```
targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");

switch(targets.Length)
{
    case 0:
        transArray = targets;
        target = null;
        break;

    case 1:
        transArray = targets;
        target = transArray[0];
        break; 

    default:
        transArray = new Transform[Random.Range(0, targets.Length)];

        for (int i = 0; i < transArray.Length; i++)
        {
             transArray[i] = targets[i].transform;
        }

        target = transArray[transArray.Length - 1];
        break;
}
```

Btw: Not sure but if what you are trying is actually to get a random target you could also simply do

```
target = targets[Random.Range(0, targets.Length)].transform;
```